# Understanding input shape to PyTorch conv1D?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

This seems to be one of the common questions on here ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62162576/calculating-shape-of-conv1d-layer-in-pytorch), [2](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/convolutional-nn-for-text-input/3442), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56845144/dataset-shape-mismatch-conv1d-input-layer)), but I am still struggling to define the right shape for input to [PyTorch conv1D](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html).

I have text sequences of length 512 (number of tokens per sequence) with each token being represented by a vector of length 768 (embedding). The batch size I am using is 6.

So my input tensor to conv1D is of shape [6, 512, 768].

```
input = torch.randn(6, 512, 768)
```

Now, I want to convolve over the length of my sequence (512) with a kernel size of 2 using the conv1D layer from PyTorch.

Understanding 1:

I assumed that "in_channels" are the embedding dimension of the conv1D layer. If so, then a conv1D layer will be defined in this way where

```
in_channels = embedding dimension (768)
out_channels = 100 (arbitrary number)
kernel = 2

convolution_layer = nn.conv1D(768, 100, 2)
feature_map = convolution_layer(input)
```

But with this assumption, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size 100 768 2, expected input `[4, 512, 768]` to have 768 channels, but got 512 channels instead
```

Understanding 2:

Then I assumed that "in_channels" is the sequence length of the input sequence. If so, then a conv1D layer will be defined in this way where

```
in_channels = sequence length (512)
out_channels = 100 (arbitrary number)
kernel = 2

convolution_layer = nn.conv1D(512, 100, 2) 
feature_map = convolution_layer(input)
```

This works fine and I get an output feature map of dimension `[batch_size, 100, 767]`. However, I am confused. Shouldn't the convolutional layer convolve over the sequence length of 512 and output a feature map of dimension `[batch_size, 100, 511]`?

I will be really grateful for your help.

Comment: In general, PyTorch nn modules work on (N, C_in, \*) input and they output (N, C_out, \*), where C_in and C_out the * dims are the ones in which the "operation takes place". This is true for all Conv*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In pytorch your input shape of [6, 512, 768] should actually be [6, 768, 512] where the feature length is represented by the channel dimension and sequence length is the length dimension. Then you can define your conv1d with in/out channels of 768 and 100 respectively to get an output of [6, 100, 511].

Given an `input` of shape [6, 512, 768] you can convert it to the correct shape with [`Tensor.transpose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.transpose).

```
input = input.transpose(1, 2).contiguous()
```

The `.contiguous()` ensures the memory of the tensor is stored contiguously which helps avoid potential issues during processing.

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer to it ([source](https://gist.github.com/spro/c87cc706625b8a54e604fb1024106556)).

So, usually, BERT outputs vectors of shape

```
[batch_size, sequence_length, embedding_dim].
```

where,

**sequence_length** = number of words or tokens in a sequence (max_length sequence BERT can handle is 512)
**embedding_dim** = the vector length of the vector describing each token (768 in case of BERT).

thus, `input = torch.randn(batch_size, 512, 768)`

Now, we want to convolve over the text sequence of length 512 using a kernel size of 2.

So, we define a PyTorch conv1D layer as follows,

```
convolution_layer = nn.conv1d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size)
```

where,

**in_channels** = embedding_dim
**out_channels** = arbitrary int
**kernel_size** = 2 (I want bigrams)

thus, `convolution_layer = nn.conv1d(768, 100, 2)`

Now we need a connecting link between the expected input by `convolution_layer` and the actual input.

For this, we require to

current input shape [batch_size, 512, 768]
expected input [batch_size, 768, 512]

To achieve this expected input shape, we need to use the transpose function from PyTorch.

```
input_transposed = input.transpose(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion for you which may not be what you asked for but might help. Because your input is `(6, 512, 768)` you can use conv2d instead of 1d.

All you need to do is to add a dimension of 1 at index 1: `input.unsqueeze(1)` which works as your channel (consider it as a grayscale image)

```
def forward(self, x):
        x = self.embedding(x) # [Batch, seq length, Embedding] = [5, 512, 768])
        x = torch.unsqueeze(x, 1) #  [5, 1, 512, 768]) # like a grayscale image
```

and also for your conv2d layer, you can define like this:

````
window_size=3 # for trigrams
EMBEDDING_SIZE = 768
NUM_FILTERS = 10 # or whatever you want
self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 1,
                      out_channels = NUM_FILTERS,
                      kernel_size = [window_size, EMBEDDING_SIZE], 
                      padding=(window_size - 1, 0))```
````