# Definition of "channels" in PyTorch Conv1d and Conv2d layers

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am working with PyTorch, and trying to figure out the dimensions required for Conv1d layers. I know that my question is nearly a repeat of [Understanding input shape to PyTorch conv1D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62372938/understanding-input-shape-to-pytorch-conv1d), but the solution there has raised more questions than answers for me, as described below.

I have successfully used Conv2d layers for an image segmentation problem, where my inputs where images. As per the PyTorch documentation, the input dimensions to a Conv2d layer are [N, C, H, W], so in my context, my input dimensions were [N_obs_per_batch, N_measurements_per_obs, N_pix, N_pix]. E.g. with 3 input measurements (intensity in 3 wavelength bands), images that were 250 by 250 pixels, and 16 observations in each batch, this was [16, 3, 250, 250].

However, I am now struggling to apply this logic to a Conv1d layer. As per the PyTorch documentation, the input dimensions to a Conv1d layer are [N, C, L], so in my understanding, my input dimensions should be [N_obs_per_batch, N_measurements_per_obs, N_samples_per_obs]. For example, with one input measurement (intensity), 1000 samples per observation (the number of timestamps at which the intensity was measured), and 5 observations per batch, shouldn't the input dimensions be [5, 1, 1000]? This is clearly incorrect, since it throws an error (see below for model architecture):

`RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [2000, 1000, 3], expected input[5, 1, 1000] to have 1000 channels, but got 1 channels instead`

Based on this error, and on the solution given in [Understanding input shape to PyTorch conv1D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62372938/understanding-input-shape-to-pytorch-conv1d), it seems to be reading the third dimension as the number of measurements per observation, not the second dimension. This led me to believe that perhaps for the Conv1d layers, "channels" refers the number of samples per observation, not the number of measurements per observation as was the case for Conv2d. However, if I remake my inputs to be of the dimensions [5, 1000, 1], I get the following error:

`RuntimeError: Calculated padded input size per channel: (1). Kernel size: (3). Kernel size can't be greater than actual input size`

This is confusing to me. If it is reading "input size per channel" to be 1, that implies that it is reading the third dimension (now 1) as the number of channels. This goes against the documentation which says channels are the second dimension.

For context, here is a (paired down) version of my network that produces these errors:

```
class ConvNN(nn.Module):
  '''
  1D convolutional NN
  '''

  def __init__(self, input_dim=1000, output_dim=2, k_size=3): 
    super(ConvNN, self).__init__()
    self.convs = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv1d(input_dim, 2000, kernel_size=k_size),
        nn.Conv1d(2000, 3000, kernel_size=k_size))
    self.linears = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(3000, 500),
        nn.Linear(500, 40]),
        nn.Linear(40, output_dim))

  def forward(self, x):
    x = self.convs(x)
    x = self.linears(x)
    return x
```

Answer (score 1):

The doc reads: `torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels, out_channels,`...

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html

Your code effectively seems to be: `nn.Conv1d(1000, 2000, kernel_size=3)`. In other words you're constructing a conv1d that handles N x C x dim where C=1000. You gave it an input where C=1.

> For example, with one input measurement (intensity), 1000 samples per observation (the number of timestamps at which the intensity was measured), and 5 observations per batch, shouldn't the input dimensions be [5, 1, 1000]?

Yes, but you need to pass that input to a conv1d that expects 1 channel. Yours expects 1000 channels. Your parameter called "input_dim" should probably be called "input_channels" since that's how you use it.

e.g.:

```
c=nn.Conv1d(1000, 2000, kernel_size=3)
c(torch.randn( (5, 1000, 1000) ) ) # <-- this works
c(torch.randn( (5, 1, 1000) ) ) # <-- Given groups=1, weight of size [2000, 1000, 3]...

c=nn.Conv1d(1, 2, kernel_size=3)
c(torch.randn( (5, 1, 1000) ) ) # <-- this works
```

FYI it's generally going to be better practice to just post the particular call that's giving you trouble. with the whole model I can't actually see what you passed to the conv, or even if my assumption about your value for `input_dim` is correct.

Comment: Aha! Thanks @nairbiv. That was indeed the issue - it is obvious to me now that input_dim should be 1 not 1000. That was a typo, and for some reason I did not immediately register it was wrong.